# I need a logic algorithm to sort soccer league mathces on a program

Tags: sorting, math, logic

Im hosting a soccer tournament (and programing a system to manage it).
The competition is a league where there are 3 groups of 10 teams each (for a total of 30 teams).
And every team has to play against every other team which is not on the same group.

Example

**GROUP A**
TeamA1
TeamA2
TeamA3
TeamA4
TeamA5
TeamA6
TeamA7
TeamA8
TeamA9
TeamA10

**GROUP B**
TeamB1
TeamB2
TeamB3
TeamB4
TeamB5
TeamB6
TeamB7
TeamB8
TeamB9
TeamB10

**GROUP C**
TeamC1
TeamC2
TeamC3
TeamC4
TeamC5
TeamC6
TeamC7
TeamC8
TeamC9
TeamC10

So for instance, every team from Group A has to play against every team from B and C but NOT vs a team from A, and so on.

The competition lasts 20 days with of course 15 matchs every day.

I need some kind of system that generates every day matches respeting the rule that avoids teams facing same group teams.

I need help just on the logic, then I can translate it to code.
It might not soundvery hard to achieve but im strugling a lot!

thank you very much!

Comment: Does each team play only one game per day? If so it seems the 20 day competition is not possible.

Comment: Yes, every day, all teams play only one match. A team from A for instance has to play with 10 teams from B and 10 from C in the competition, giving 20 matches in total. And like that with every team. Why do you think 20 day competition isn't possible? Thanks for your time btw

Comment: Assume all Group A teams play all Group B teams on day 1 - then Group C has no one to play on day one - so given the 1 game per day limitation - Group C teams cannot play 20 games in 20 days.  This holds true no matter which combinations chosen.

Answer (score 0):

How I would do this is as follows:

Iterate through Group A, for each team on A I would match them with a team via group B and C and save each pairing in some sort of variable. This would create all the A vs B and A vs C pairings.

Then I would iterate through Group B, but only match against Group C as all the A vs B (which I assume in this context is equivalent to B vs A) matches have been paired. This would pair all the B vs C matches.

So we end up with all the A vs B, A vs C, and B vs C match ups. Which if the equivalency I assumed earlier is true takes care of all the matches.